# How to compare different Information Retrieval Methods?

Tags: nlp, comparison, search-engine, word2vec, information-retrieval

I have an algorithm that takes an user's query and include relevant terms in it to expand it and get better results in document retrieval.
Now, I have to write a paper about it in which i have to compare it's performance with other IR Methods.

How do I do that ? What other IR Methods exist?
Is there any tool which works on different datasets and can be used to compare different IR Methods ?

Comment: This is not the best place to ask this question. Consider asking at https://cs.stackexchange.com/ And yes, there are many distinct IR Methods. PM me so I can send you my dissertation, there you can find some references to start with.

Comment: Okay i'll ask there. Also How do I PM you ? I saw that I cant create a chat room yet. Thanks !

Comment: I'll post it here.

Comment: Check it out: https://drive.google.com/open?id=12gWLx2saFe5mZI96roUG_p1YfzrqVNbx It's about question answering, however IR is closely related to it. Also, check F-score and Precision metrics to evaluate your results.